# Setter methods in UDT in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I'm still new to this and trying to get my head around it. UDT are able to define methods which you can call on the object stored, I seem to create a method that returns a value fine but was wondering if it's possible create a setter methods. This scenario isn't really useful but it's simple just for clarification

For example, I have this type:

```
create TYPE TestType2 AS OBJECT(
Numb NUMBER(4),
Str VARCHAR2(10),
MEMBER FUNCTION setNum(numba NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
);
```

Which compiles fine so my assumption setter methods are allow
I've tried create the body type below:

```
CREATE TYPE BODY TestType2 as
member function setNum(numba NUMBER) return NUMBER is
    begin
        SELF.Numb := numba;
        return SELF.Numb;
    END;
END;
```

However this won't work giving me the errors below:

```
Error(3,9): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(3,14): PLS-00363: expression 'SELF.NUMB' cannot be used as an assignment target
```

Is there a way to create a set method or is this only allowed in store procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an obscure error. The problem is member functions take an implicit parameter of SELF. So if you want to change something you need to make the parameter explicit:

```
create or replace TYPE TestType2 AS OBJECT(   
    Numb NUMBER(4,0),
    Str VARCHAR2(10),
    MEMBER procedure setNum(self in out TestType2, numba NUMBER )
 );
/
CREATE or replace TYPE BODY TestType2 as
    member function setNum(self in out TestType2 , numba NUMBER) return NUMBER 
    is
    begin
        self.Numb := numba;
        return SELF.Numb;
    END;
END;
/
```

Note that the SELF parameter remains implicit when calling the function:

```
declare
   t TestType2 := TestType2(4, 'TEST');
   n pls_integer;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('1' || t.numb);
    n := t.setNum(8);
    dbms_output.put_line('2' || t.numb);
end;
/
```

Incidentally, setter methods don't need to be functions; we can have member procedures too.

```
create or replace TYPE TestType2 AS OBJECT(
    Numb NUMBER(4,0),
    Str VARCHAR2(10),
    MEMBER procedure setNum(self in out TestType2, numba NUMBER ),
    MEMBER FUNCTION getNum RETURN NUMBER
);
/
CREATE or replace TYPE BODY TestType2 as
    member procedure setNum(self in out TestType2, numba NUMBER )
is
    begin
        self.Numb := numba;
    END;

    MEMBER FUNCTION getNum RETURN NUMBER
    is
    begin
        return self.numb;
    end;
END;
/
```

Comment: Whats the difference between a member procedure and function? Initially I thought functions were limited to declared types and procedures were a generic function that irregardless of type?

Comment: Nope that's not a distinction. Functions return a value and procedures don't, that's it.